# Is this tag [note] worthy?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-disambiguation

The [note](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/note) tag currently has no summary, [wiki entry](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/note/info), or [synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/note/synonyms). Its usage doesn't seem to be clear cut:

- Does it refer to the OS X [Notes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29217469/4200092) app?
- Or "sticky notes" in, for example, [Microsoft Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28675588/4200092)?
- Or those [music](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27305657/4200092) [things](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27159433/4200092)?
- Or the [Android thing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24505796/4200092)?
- Or an abbreviation for [Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20808343/4200092)?
- Or is it [just a word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28054449/4200092) that you can use sometimes?

I've tagged this as "disambiguation" rather than a burnination request, but deletion might be the best option given the ambiguity of the word.

Comment: The top 3 related tags are all Android tags.  Probably because of the Samsung Galaxy Note, a popular device.  I don't see any Android tags in your profile, be careful to not kill what you don't know.

Comment: This could mean anything - I'd burn it...if someone is developing on the Note, they can tag it "Android".

Comment: @HansPassant Android uses only make up about 1/7th of the questions.  Equal uses are Java calendars, Apple's Notes app and music notes.  Besides, we already have a tag for the Samsung Galaxy Note, [galaxy].  You don't have to be an Android expert to know that 5 meanings is not equal to 1 meaning.

Comment: I have to agree with @JasonMArcher. This tag is too broad and doesn't add value. It should be burinated.
Also, creative title. Very punny.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This tag is way too broad and adds nothing of value to any of the 43 questions that it adorns, so I've removed it from them, and the tag should be removed from the system within the next 24 hours.

Comment: Thank you for completing the job. (I cleaned 20 or so for you before you got to see just 43 questions left — and I'd not be surprised to find someone else, or several other people, also helped.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler That's what I thought (43 didn't seem like as many as the question implied); I didn't mean to suggest that I did the job on my own.

Comment: I didn't think that you meant to suggest you did the job on your own. I appreciate you finishing the work.  I went back to get some more done, and couldn't find anything to do, so I came here and found that you'd finished it.  It takes time, even if you don't edit anything other than the tag (but in my experience, more than 50% of the questions need more work than just the tag removal).